# User not authorized to perform RunTask on a Amazon ECS Fargate (scheduled task)

Tags: aws-cloudformation, scheduled-tasks, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Obs: *problem solved, solution at the end of the question.*

I'm provisioning an ECS Fargate in CloudFormation. I created a scheduled task to run every 50 min and uploaded the scheduled task with the appropriate settings and it is loaded in the AWS console. But there are failed invocations and the message in CloudTrail is:
**"User: arn:aws:sts::XXX:assumed-role/CloudWatchBackupEventRoleSA/0b3175d7b79e37638d901f6fbd132647 is not authorized to perform: ecs:RunTask on resource: arn:aws:ecs:sa-east-1:XXX:task-definition/family-metrics:10"**

The resource TaskDefinition, TaskDefinitionRole and CloudWatchEvECSRole (this one has actions like RunTask and PassRole):

```
TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    # DependsOn: Listener
    Properties:
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref TaskExecutionRole
      TaskRoleArn: !Ref TaskExecutionRole
      Cpu: !Ref ContainerCpu
      Memory: !Ref ContainerMemory
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Sub ${ContainerName}
          Image: !Sub '${ImageName}'
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: !Ref ExposedPortInDockerfile
          Cpu: !Ref ContainerCpu
          Memory: !Ref ContainerMemory
          MemoryReservation: !Ref ContainerMemoryReservation
          Essential: true
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-region: !Sub "${AWS::Region}"
              awslogs-group: !Sub "${Feature}-${Micro}"
              awslogs-stream-prefix: !Sub "${Feature}-${Micro}"
      Family: !Sub "family-${Feature}-${Micro}"
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
    DependsOn: CloudWatchLogGroup

TaskExecutionRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: policy-name
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: "Allow"
              Action:
                - ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
                - ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability
                - ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer
                - ecr:BatchGetImage
                - logs:CreateLogStream
                - logs:PutLogEvents
              Resource: "*"

CloudWatchEvECSRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - events.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: CloudwatchEventsInvECSRunTask
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: 2012-10-17
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: 'ecs:RunTask'
              Resource: !Ref TaskDefinition
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: 'iam:PassRole'
              Resource: !GetAtt TaskExecutionRole.Arn
```

Suggestions on how to accomplish this are greatly appreciate.

---

**[RESOLUTION]**

This error occurred due to the container image. I assigned a name to load the container images different from what was in the ECR. After resolving this divergence, the tasks ran.

Comment: What is `CloudWatchBackupEventRoleSA`?

Comment: @Marcin In AWS console is the Target Role (inside Target in Scheduled Tasks). I just gave a different name.